# remove value in array Swiftui

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I cant delete a value in an array. I get the following error message:

> Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Equatable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

This is my code in the main file:

```
            if let index = loader.userfl.firstIndex(of: user?.uid ?? "") {
                loader.userfl.remove(at: index)
            }
```

this is what i do in the loader file:

```
    @Published var userfl = []
```

Does anyone know what i do wrong?

Comment: you need to show more code and info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add the type to the variable to it becomes:

```
@Published var userfl: [String] = []
```

Comment: The error message that OP shared explain about some issue with **Equatable**, I am wandering how could be your answer solving that problem!

Comment: Hello! I think the problem lies in that the method "firstIndex(of:)" requires the array to have _elements_ that are **Equatable**. However, the array was initialized without a type (it was left for the compiler to implicitly assign a type later). The method "firstIndex(of:)" requires the array to have a type which is **Equatable**, but the compiler does not know yet (because it is implicit). Therefore, when setting the type [String], the method "firstIndex(of:)" can assure that it has equatable elements. (P.S.: String conforms to Equatable)

Comment: So how did you guess it should be [String] ?, it could be [Int] or [Double] or . . .

Comment: Hello! Good question sorry I missed explaining that point. I used the fact that in the original code it said "firstIndex(of: user?.uid ?? "")" Since there was **?? ""**, I implied it was a String array.